# About securing password field in textformfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to hide completely the password field, I set obscure text true but it shows the characters as I type them how hide completely the characters?

Comment: Can you include your current snippet ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want completely hide it, you must use controller and implement like this:

```
class TextFieldPassWord extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextFieldPassWordState createState() => _TextFieldPassWordState();
}

class _TextFieldPassWordState extends State<TextFieldPassWord> {
  String _valueShow = "";
  String _value = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextField(
        controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
          TextEditingValue(
            text: _valueShow,
            selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _valueShow.length),
          ),
        ),
        onChanged: (String str) {
          String value = "";
          if (str.length > _value.length) {
            value += str.substring(_value.length, str.length);
          }
          if (str.length < _value.length) {
            value = _value.substring(1, str.length);
          }
          String valueToShow = "*" * str.length;
          setState(() {
            _valueShow = valueToShow;
            _value = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why complicating simple stuffs?

Comment: I think his desire is when input a character, it immediatly obsure, the obsureText parameter only hide character after 1 second.